# Create Jpa EntityManager that manages MongoDb connection with java code configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-ogm

I need to define two different persistent units, one for a mysql db and the other for a mongodb, I'm trying to create with Spring's @Configuration the entityManager that will manage Mongo but the application fails at Spring's bootstrap with the following error: Error creating bean with name 'mongoEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/intraway/qx/utilities/config/SpringDataJpaMongoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

```
    Java config Class
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.intraway.qx.utilities.models.repositories.mongoRepository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mongoEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "mongoTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringDataJpaMongoConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "mongoEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean  mongoEntityManager() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "resource_local");
        properties.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider","mongodb");
        properties.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.host","localhost");
        properties.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.port", "27017");
        properties.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.database", "qx_utils");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.intraway.qx.utilities.models");
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("persistence.mongo");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        em.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernateOgmPersistence.class);
        return em;
    }
    @Bean(name = "mongoTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(mongoEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

POM.xml
    
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

```
    <groupId>com.intraway.qx</groupId>
    <artifactId>QX-AOS-Utilities</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>QX-AOS-Utilities</name>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repositories -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I need to configure the DB connection programatically (NOT through application.properties file) that's a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know if you used `@Primary` annotation in MySQL DB config.
But If you're using two DataSources, you have to set one of them Primary.

You can follow this tutorial, even it uses properties, but you can get into them to the configuration class as well.

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

**4. Create a Configuration Class for the Oracle database “foo” named 
“FooDbConfig.java”**

**package com.foobar;**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
  basePackages = { "com.foobar.foo.repo" }
)
public class FooDbConfig {

@Primary
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```